# How to serve a request by responding with another website's response?

Tags: python, django, http

I have setup an e-commerce store using a e-commerce provider. I have my own subdomain (mysubdomain.ecommerce.com). I own mydomain.com. I'd like my store to live at mydomain.com/store. In other words, I'd like mydomain.com/store to display whatever mysubdomain.ecommerce.com displays, without changing the url in the browser.

How would I accomplish this in Django?

Comment: These are all your requirements. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are thinking is called [proxying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). Any web server can do it (Nginx, Apache). Unlike Django, web servers are designed to accomplish this function and give better performance and reliability with much less hassle.

In theory one can write custom views to do proxying in Django, but it is approach of more pain.

[I suggest you take a look example for Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite).

However the client application (mysubdomain.ecommerce.com) must support rewriting URL and setting canoncial URL of the site to `mydomain.com/store`. If your ecommerce providing doesn't support it you might have a lot of issues. Again, in theory, you can parse proxyed HTML and rewrite links, but it rarely works very well.

My suggestion is simply to contact your eCommerce provider (sounds like commercial, closed solution) and ask them how to do it.